# How to create a react pdf viewer with multiple langauge support

Tags: reactjs, frontend, i18next, react-pdf-viewer

I have tried creating a react pdf viewer using react-pdf library , i want to integrate a functionality of changing language of the content of pdf according to drop down menu of language selection . Can anybody help ?

i have tried localisation : which only changes content of react created components not that of users , also have used i18n but could make it work !